# Can I Activate Wormholes and Gateways in Federation/Vassal territory in Stellaris

Tags: stellaris

Despite having wormhole stabilization and gateway repair technologies, I don't have any of either in my territory. I do have Vassals and Federation allies with both though.

I've sent a Science Vessel to the Wormhole and a Construction Vessel to the Gateway, but no new controls or options have appeared anywhere. Am I missing something would the options only be available in my territory?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I think I've now worked this out:

1. The only way to instruct a science vessel to explore an unstabilised wormhole is via the right click menu. You can right-click and explore any wormhole your science ship can reach, regardless of its territory. Once it's explored, the two systems with an endpoint for the wormhole become adjacent from your fleet's perspective, so just imagine there's a really long hyperlane between them. Note that wormholes are only stabilised for their empire, so if your opponent learns to stabilise a wormhole into your territory and you haven't, better get on that quick...
2. Gateways can be constructed or repaired. You can also construct Gateways in the territory of your vassals, but not your allies.